# Reset button LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, actionlistener, restart

I am making a pong game and what i want to do is when the ball goes past the players paddle for the ball to go back to the middle(which i have done) and a button to come up that when we press it the velocity of the ball goes back to how it was (the game restarts).
 what i have already is the game resets when a player scores. Ive added the button and actionlistener but the actionlistener doesnt restart the game. Here is my code:

```
public void StartAgain(){
        if(resetButton = true){
        int playButtonWidth = ballPong.getBallSizeX();
        int playButtonHeight = ballPong.getBallSizeY();
        ResetButtonStage = new Stage();
        skin = new Skin();

        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);
        style = new LabelStyle(font, Color.WHITE);

        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons/playButton.pack");
        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);


        playButtonStyle = new TextButtonStyle();

        playButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("play");
        playButtonStyle.over = skin.getDrawable("play_pressed");
        playButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("play_pressed");
        playButtonStyle.font = font;

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Play button

        playButton = new TextButton("", playButtonStyle);
        //buttonStyle.font.setScale((float) 0.5);   

        playButton.setWidth(playButtonWidth);
        playButton.setHeight(playButtonHeight);
        playButton.setPosition(100,250);
        ResetButtonStage.addActor(playButton);

        playButton.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ballPong.ballVectorX = ballPong.getBallSpeed();
                ballPong.ballVectorY = ballPong.getBallSpeed();
                resetButton = false;
                return true;
            }
        });

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(ResetButtonStage);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        ResetButtonStage.act();
        ResetButtonStage.draw();
    }
    }
```

what ive tried to do is create a boolean called resetButton and set it to false, and when a player scores it sets the boolean to true, thus showing the button. However, ive gone about this the wrong way. Ive done it so when the balls position is below the paddle the game resets and the StartAgain() method shows. But obviously the position of the ball is now above the paddle (as it has reset) so the startAgain method wont be running.

```
if(ballPong.getPosition().y<= 1){
            player2Score = player2Score +1;
            System.out.println("bottom");
            StartAgain();
            resetButton = true;
            if(ballPong.reset ==true){

                    ballPong.reset();
            }           
        }
```

What I'm asking is, where should i call this StartAgain() method and how can I get the actionlistener working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of your `startAgain` method only executes if `resetButton = true`, but when you check to see if `ballPong.getPosition().y<= 1` you're not setting `resetButton = true` until after calling `StartAgain()`.

Set `resetButton = true` first, so that when you call `StartAgain()` it can pass the `if (resetButton = true)` check.

It is difficult to guess where this code sits in your libGdx project. Is it in the `render()` of a screen? Please show the code around where you have placed your `if(ballPong.getPosition().y<= 1)` statement.

Guessing at it's location, you could adjust your `if` statement to also consider the current state of the `resetButton` boolean.

```
if(ballPong.getPosition().y<= 1 || resetButton == true){
    player2Score = player2Score +1;
    System.out.println("bottom");
    resetButton = true;
    StartAgain();
    if(ballPong.reset ==true){
        ballPong.reset();
    }           
}
```

Comment: doesnt work. its only setting it to true if the ball is below the paddle. so when i reset it it goes to the origin which is above the paddle so the button doesnt show anymore :(